# Is it a good trial to build such a class?

Tags: java

```
class IdPwPair {

  private String pw = "";
  private String id = "";

  //Constructor

  //getter & setter

 }
```

That is because I want to put a large number of IDs and their passwords into an array.

And, I may want to add a field accountType, then Map won't work anymore.

Comment: may be you can to use char[] for pw,check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords

Comment: Variables should be in lowerCamelcase. Passwords should be stored as `char[]`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why is using a `char[]` suggested ?

Comment: I corrected it. Forum made me a little nervous. I know HashMap can do the thing. However I don't feel good with ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>. Then the question becomes, is HashMap the common solution?

Comment: @LittleChild this is for security reasons. If you use a `String` then it is immutable - even if you deference the `String` it will be on the heap/in the pool. If you use a `char[]` you can zero it when you're done thereby removing the password from memory.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah I looked for it. Found `Jon Skeet`'s answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for a class would be as follows:

```
class IdPwPair {
  final public String id, password;

  public IdPwPair(String id, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

***Explanation***

What you want to design is a data-holder class. It is strongly recommended to use the final keyword here and not add a setter, because this class does not *control* the data, only hold it together.

This not only makes accessing the data easier (and faster), it as well allows for a much simpler code structure. Instead of having to track when and where you change the content of a dataset, you just use them and throw them away if they are no longer valid. This ensures that a given set of data at any time either holds the exact one set of information, or doesn't exist anymore. Not even a chance to mess up here by accidentally changing the data while someone else was still using it.

Note: There are security concerns for keeping passwords in JVM memory, because someone could live-hack the JVM and pull out the passwords. So if you are working on a software where this is a concern (which I doubt), you should use `char[]` instead and overwrite the content once it is no longer used.

Comment: The 'which i doubt' part is very insightful.^^  You hava given out a very good suggestion I think.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it makes sense to create `class` and later uses it as `list<class>`... better is to use `char[]` for password to get benefits of security, processing and manipulating purposes..

Comment: Would I be correct in saying `char[]`s are better for passwords because it is easier to control when they are destroyed whereas a String can hang around before being garbage collected?

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, that is the thinking behind the recommendation.

Comment: Yes, agree with you... and manipulation and processing is also easy on password e.g. making some encrypt/decrypt logic etc...

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain _why_ this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an `ArrayList<String>` for both `Pw` and `Id`

or

`HashMap<String,String>`which will map each id to its password.

Using a `char[]` is preferred for storing passwords because you can explicitly wipe the data after you are done even before GC comes in.

Comment: Thank you all for mention the naming convention. Two arrayList is not good for iterate from my perspective of view.

Comment: @bijiDango `HashMap` then ? Look into `char[]` for password storage.

Comment: Using two distinct Lists for modelling some domain object which has a clear 1:1 relation between id and password is certainly an antipattern...

Comment: @GyroGearless I am a learner myself. Could you point me to some resource where I could learn this ? =)

Answer (score 0):

First of all use lowercase start as follows

```
  private String pw = "";
  private String id = "";
```

creating a class is depends on your requirement. you can use your `HashMap<String,String>` for this.

```
 Map<String,String> idOverPassword= new HashMap<String,String>();
 idOverPassword.put("id","password");
```

Comment: may be you could have given this info in comment

Comment: I corrected it. Forum made me a little nervous.